# How are directories managed in the filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, directory

On behalf of this particular [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5711/why-does-have-an-entry) I would like to know how directories are managed in the file system. What does the author of the above question mean by telling

> each directory has n+2 pointers to
>   itself

I would like to get more clarity and info on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, any directory that contains n sub-directories has n+2 links to itself.

Every directory has a '.' entry that's a link to itself.
Every directory's parent has a link to it.

That's 2 links.

Every sub-directory has a '..' in it, which is a link to the directory in question.  If your directory has n directories in it, that's n links.

So a total of n+2 links to any given directory.

Comment: Thanks, but can you give me a detail explanation on how are directories maintained by the file system? At least some pointers to it.

Comment: The problem with that question is that no two filesystems do directories the same way. In some (SysV, FFS) directories are just files, albeit with a specified organization. In ResierFS, they're part of a database, almost: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReiserFS#Design  .  That question has as many answers as there are filesystems.

Answer (score 2):

Linux filesystems are all POSIX compliant and rely on an [inode pointer structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode_pointer_structure) to represent directory relations. Apart from the above Wikipedia link, you can have a look at the [POSIX inode description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode#POSIX_inode_description), or the IBM article on '[The anatomy of the Linux filesystem](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-linux-filesystem/)'.