# Why are there lots of hard links in /usr

Tags: hard-link

I've read [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20670/why-do-hard-links-exist), now I simply want to know why there are lots of hard link in `/usr`.

For example, in my Ubuntu server, installed `git`, I found the command `git` here: `/usr/bin/git`. I execute `ls -l /usr/bin/git` and get the output as below:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 119 root root 11178080 Mar  6 03:48 /usr/bin/git
```

As you see, there are 119 hard links...

Why do we need 119 hard links here? More generally speaking, as we have the environment variable `PATH` and the executable files have been put into `/usr/bin/`, also, we can create soft links for some reason of compatibility, we can execute them anytime and anywhere, why are there some hard links in `usr`?

Part of output of `find /usr -samefile /usr/bin/git`:

```
/usr/libexec/git-core/git-prune
/usr/libexec/git-core/git-diff-index
/usr/libexec/git-core/git-ls-remote
/usr/libexec/git-core/git-merge-recursive
/usr/libexec/git-core/git-push
/usr/libexec/git-core/git-update-index
/usr/libexec/git-core/git-check-mailmap
/usr/libexec/git-core/git-interpret-trailers
/usr/libexec/git-core/git-archive
/usr/libexec/git-core/git-upload-archive
/usr/libexec/git-core/git-rev-parse
/usr/libexec/git-core/git-ls-files
/usr/libexec/git-core/git-am
```

All of hard links of `/usr/bin/git` are found in `/usr/libexec/git-core/`.

Comment: My Ubuntu 16.04 does not have 119 hard links to git. I get just `1` there. ... in fact, the only files which have hard links in my `/usr/bin` are a bunch of perl commands and `python3.5`, and that's probably some quirk of Perl and Python installation process.

Comment: Even assuming 119 hard links, what's wrong with using hard links as long as it's in the same filesystem? Put another way: why should symlinks be used instead of hard links?

Comment: FWIW on Arch I have three hard links to `/usr/bin/git`, to `/usr/bin/git{,-receive-pack,-upload-archive}`, and on Debian I have only one.

Comment: Can you find which other files are links to it? `find /usr -samefile /usr/bin/git` should give you a list. The git package doesn't have them itself so I'm curious what does.

Comment: An 11MB `git` binary makes it seem like this was installed from source, unstripped...

Comment: @MichaelHomer see my re-edition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `git` links have nothing to do with the PATH, they’re a space-saving measure.

Generally speaking, in most cases for “installed” software, hard links are preferable to symbolic links when possible, because they’re more efficient and resilient. You’ll see quite a few binaries in `/usr/bin` with hard links, including `perl`, and that’s fine.

`git` packages do tend to use symbolic links instead, because of the large number of links involved and [the problems that can cause](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=642603). If you install `git` from source, it will use hard links by default if at all possible; you can disable that by adding `NO_INSTALL_HARDLINKS=1` to the `make install` command’s arguments.

Comment: Oh I see, I did install git from source. This should be why I got so many hard links... I installed git from source because https://askubuntu.com/questions/186847/error-gnutls-handshake-failed-when-connecting-to-https-servers/187199#187199

Answer (score 3):

Often, a single binary with multiple related functions has multiple hard links, in order to let each function have a distinct, memorable command, and still not duplicate any code that all those functions might have in common.

Making the various functions of a single binary appear as distinct commands is also an easy, shell-independent way to make the functions TAB-completable: for example, in `bash`, if you only remember the first few letters of some command, just type the letters you remember and press TAB twice: you'll get a list of all commands with those initial letters.

Symbolic links can also be used for this, but if all the linked commands are expected to be in the same directory, hard links are the most space-efficient solution: instead of duplicating an entire file, or just using up an extra inode like a symlink might do (on some filesystems), a hard link occupies just a directory entry.

If you want to, you can easily make a script behave like this too:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "${0##*/}" in
    name1)
        # do something
        ;;
    name2)
        # do something else
        ;;
    *)
        # output an error message, or perhaps usage instructions
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: I think that there is no "might" about it.  Be confident!  (-:  Do you actually know of _any_ filesystem formats where a symbolic link does not use an i-node?  How do they square that with the necessary semantics of `lstat()`?

Comment: NFS, XFS and Btrfs are mentioned as examples where a symlink is not stored within an inode, but on closer inspection it seems to mean on those filesystems a symlink consumes an inode *plus* some other stuff.