# cd .. on root folder

Tags: directory, cd-command

Why `cd ..`, typed at root folder, does not warn or fails with an error?

I would expect:

```
/$ cd ..
-bash: cd: ..: No such file or directory
```

Instead, I'm left at `/`. Of course, this is since `..` does exist in `/`, and is simply `/`, just like `.`. I just wonder why it is like that.

Comment: No answer, but [here](https://plus.google.com/+RobPikeTheHuman/posts/R58WgWwN9jp) is a  good associated read, Rob Pike on G+ discussing the origin of the dotfile(s).

Comment: Archive of like Rob Pike link now that Google+ has shut down: https://web.archive.org/web/20190217232242/https://plus.google.com/+RobPikeTheHuman/posts/R58WgWwN9jp

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/186184/the-parent-of-the-root-directory

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5711/why-does-have-an-entry

Answer (score 54, accepted):

According to the Open Group (responsible for the POSIX standard):

> Each directory has exactly one parent directory which is represented by the name **dot-dot** in the first directory.
>   [...]
>   What the filename **dot-dot** refers to relative to the root directory is implementation-defined. In Version 7 it refers to the root directory itself; this is the behavior mentioned in POSIX.1-2008. In some networked systems the construction **/../hostname/** is used to refer to the root directory of another host, and POSIX.1 permits this behavior.

[A.4.13 Pathname Resolution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap04.html#tag_21_04_13)

> The dot-dot entry in the root directory is interpreted to mean the root directory itself. Thus, dot-dot cannot be used to access files outside the subtree rooted at the root directory.

[chroot - change root directory](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/chroot.html)

Answer (score 29):

You don't get an error because even the `/` directory actually *has* a valid directory entry for `..`, but unlike with other directories it points to the directory itself and thus behaves identical to `.`:

```
$ ls -lid / /. /..
128 drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4096 Apr 15 11:26 /
128 drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4096 Apr 15 11:26 /.
128 drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4096 Apr 15 11:26 /..
$
```

As the first column tells you, `.`, `..`, and `/` all have the same inode-number and thus are the same filesystem entries.

So even if you `cd ..` inside of `/` you just stay in `/`.

Comment: The question asks *why* the `..` directory entry is there.

Comment: The only reason that comes to my mind, is that you want to treat `/` just like any other folder, including a valid entry for `..`. Otherwise you would have to treat `/` differently compared to all other folders in the system.

Answer (score 16):

It's there because removing it would require creating special-case handling code in the kernel and the C libraries.  Right now you can assume that there will always be a `.` and `..` in any directory you go to.

The only special-case code required right now is in filesystem mounting code, where the code overrides the inode value of `..` to point to the directory containing the mount point, since root directories aren't always root directories.

Comment: After all, it is impossible for 'parent-referral' in tree structures to be free of any special-case handling, isn't it? The root has to be special by definition, and any attempt to mask that will lead to special cases or confusion elsewhere.

Comment: @musiphil In unix the special cases here are shuffled off to the `mount` command and its associated special file `/etc/fstab`.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason '..' is in / is that if it wasn't there it would create another special case: root directory would have one hard link fewer than all the other directories (all directory nodes have n+2 links, where n is the number of direct subdirectories inside). This would break various programs that rely on in for optimization of directory scans.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to check what `.` and `..` in `/` really is:

```
$ readlink -f ..
/home

$ readlink -f /.
/

$ readlink -f /..
/
```

As you can see, `.` and `..` is pointed to `/`.

Answer (score 0):

It's nice that it's there, because otherwise I wouldn't be able to spam `../../../../` to get to the root from a folder.  If it didn't allow the `..` at the root then I'd be stuck counting the number of folders down the working dir is.

Comment: What's wrong with `cd /`?

Comment: @Bach Sometimes, keyboard mashing is more fun.  Besides, in many circumstances you're not trying to go to the root, in which case using `../` is better.  I also do a lot of file operations in PHP, where I can't do `/` for several reasons.

Comment: The flip side is that maybe you accidentally enter too many `../`s and operate on (or remove) a file you didn't intend to without error.

Comment: Repeating `../` more times than needed and wishing it to work as intended looks like a (dormant) logic error to me, even if the filesystem apparently allows it.

Comment: @musiphil typing spaces in between commands - is a logic error (assumption that all spaces between *tail -f | grep* are a must). Most unix folks suffer from it. Typing '../..' looks like a Windows-folk problem (by default, cmd starts in X:\Windows and you have to spam .. from the beginning). Why to heal a small problem when there's a larger one? (spaces)

Comment: btw, I think that ../.. with relative_to_/_depth+1 - must redirect back to current directory (imagine broke symlinks fun after that one)

Comment: If root didn't have `..`, you could just do `while [ -d .. ]; do cd ..; done`