# How does the regular expression [\\\/][^\\\/]*$ work?

Tags: regular-expression

I've some notes of useful regular expressions and one that I always use is the following:

```
echo '/home/user/folder/file.txt' | sed -E 's/[\\\/][^\\\/]*$//g'
```

The result that I get from this regular expression is the path of the parent folder `/home/user/folder`. I understand the basics of regular expressions with:

```
\s          # all white space
\S          # no white space
.           # all chars       
\.          # period
+           # sequence of once or more
{5}         # sequence of delimited interval 
*           # sequence of zero or more
?           # sequence of once or none
[0-9]       # any sequence of number
[a-z]       # any sequence of letter 
[^x-y]      # no sequence of letter 
^           # beginning
$           # ending
```

However, I haven't managed to figure out what is the meaning of `[\\\/]` and `[^\\\/]` in the case of the regular expression from my example. How does it work?

Comment: Why don't you use what you understand and instead say `sed 's#\(.*\)/.*#\1#'` or `sed 's#/[^/]*$##'`, or use the `dirname` utility?

Comment: @Kusalananda Why is `sed 's#\(.*\)/.*#\1#'` and `sed 's#/[^/]*$##'` better than `sed 's/[/][^/]*$//'`? I made this question because I was struggling to understand that regular expression. It wasn't so much about solving the problem of getting `dirname`. Multiple times I made a mess on `bash` code because I was using `dirname` of `dirname` of `dirname`... The code can get ugly like that.

Comment: Ah, then I misunderstood why you included the list of regular expression features that you understood. And I also misunderstood what the end goal was. I thought you wanted to strip off the last part of a pathname. Note that the given regular expression does not help with stripping off arbitrary components of the pathname either, just like `dirname` does not help with that.  In the `zsh` shell, it would be a simple matter of using `$pathname:h`, `$pathname:h:h` etc.

Comment: @Kusalananda The pattern `[\\\/]` was out of it... I missed the concept that `[abc]` is `a` or `b` or `c` as explained in the accepted answer... So I wasn't understanding that it was just \ or / in the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[\\\/]` contains an escaped `\` and an escaped `/` (escaping this character is not necessary here). Like `[abc]` matches `a` or `b` or `c`, `[\\\/]` matches `\` or `/`.

`[^\\\/]` is somewhat similar but `^` is special at the beginning of `[]`: it negates the meaning. `[^\\\/]` matches any character *other* than `\` or `/`.

`[\\\/][^\\\/]*$` matches `\` or `/`, then zero or more other characters till the end of the line. Your `s` command replaces the matched string with nothing. The whole sed command removes the last `\` or the last `/` (whichever occurs later in the line) along with everything that follows in the line.

Notes:

- `-E` is not needed for this particular command to work.
- `g` is not needed (you cannot find more than one end of the line in a line).
- (already noted) Escaping `/` inside `[]` is not needed. (Escaping `/` outside of `[]` is not needed in general; it's often needed because people particularly choose `/` as the delimiter in `s/…/…/`, but it can be another character, e.g. `s|…|…|`.)
- Your command seems to be "universal" in a sense it removes the last component from Unix pathnames (components separated by `/`) and from DOS/Windows pathnames (components separated by `\`). But…
- `\` may appear in a Unix pathname. If it does then your sed command may give you an unexpected result. A newline character is also allowed.
- `/` is a valid pathname and [its parent directory is `/`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5713/108618). Your sed command yields an empty string though.
- If `dir` is a directory then `/path/to/dir/` is equivalent to `/path/to/dir`, but your sed command will yield `/path/to/dir` and `/path/to` respectively.

Comment: Cool, I actually didn't know that `[abc]` would make `a` or `b` or `c`... Most of the time I use ranges like `[a-z]` and `[0-9]`... So in the end the \\ is more about windows users and `sed -E 's/[\/][^\/]*$//g'` would be enough to make it work on Linux... With the limitations that you mentioned though. Thanks!

Comment: @raylight Even `sed 's/[/][^/]*$//'` should do.

Comment: I see... I'd be more like the case in `sed 's/\/[^/]*\/[^/]*$//g'`. Going back two folders now... That ends up being better than using `dirname` multiple times in my opinion...

Comment: If you want to mangle Unix pathnames, consider basename(1), dirname(1), or perhaps the builtins to your shell.